# Invoking node.js package directly from the windows command line

Tags: node.js

On windows, at the "Node.js command prompt" (as opened from the Start Menu), I can run the following:

```
highcharts-export-server -infile "C:\Users\bailis02\Desktop\R Export\hc.json" 
--type svg -outfile "C:\Users\bailis02\Desktop\R Export\hc.svg"
```

highcharts-export-server was installed via npm with the -g option as outlined at:
https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/blob/master/README.md

What is the best way of running the same, but directly from the standard windows command line?  I have found the following work from the windows command line:

```
"C:\Users\bailis02\AppData\Roaming\npm\highcharts-export-server.cmd" 
-infile "hc.json" --type svg -outfile "hc.svg"

"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\bailis02\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\highcharts-export-server\bin\cli.js" 
-infile "hc.json" --type svg -outfile "hc.svg"
```

Is there a smarter way of doing this, e.g. where I can just specify "highcharts-export-server" without having to specify a path into AppData\Roaming?

Comment: Note you can use `%APPDATA%` and `%LOCALAPPDATA%` to reference paths relative to these folders easily.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I was really wondering if there was a node.js shortcut way of doing this that I didn't know about, e.g. (hypothetically) node.js /highcharts-export-server ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `C:\Program Files\nodejs` to your `PATH` environment variable, you could shorten that to

```
node "C:\Users\bailis02\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\highcharts-export-server\bin\cli.js" -infile "hc.json" --type svg -outfile "hc.svg"
```

If you use [special folder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_folder) lookups:

```
node "%APPDATA%\npm\node_modules\highcharts-export-server\bin\cli.js" -infile "hc.json" --type svg -outfile "hc.svg"
```

If you do this often it could justify a script, something like this (note this is thrown together and untested):

```
import exporter from 'highcharts-export-server';

exporter.initPool();
exporter.export({
    infile: process.env.argv[2],
    type: process.env.argv[3],
    outfile: process.env.argv[4]
});
```

then you could use it like so:

```
node export.js hc.json svg hc.svg
```

And you can always tweak the arguments etc to suit your use-case.  The [highcharts-export-server documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-export-server) lists all the goodies you can use.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a documentation page somewhere on import...from....?  I had a quick look but didn't find anything all that clear.

Comment: That's known as the [ES6 Module](http://www.google.com/search?q=es6%20modules) pattern.  Glance at a few search results and pick a couple that look like the right pace for you, then go nuts :)  IMO, this pattern was one of the best parts of ES6.  Good luck!